# GoogleMaps and GeoIP: Get Lat,Long from IP and paint map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geoip

I am retrieving longitude and latitude acording to users ip, then i want to just paint the map but it wont work

```
function initialize() {
    console.log(geoip_latitude(), geoip_longitude());
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(geoip_latitude(), geoip_longitude());
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    initialize();
});
```

Firebug logs

```
google.maps.LatLng is not a constructor
[Parar en este error]   

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(geoip_latitude(), geoip_longitude());
```

Any idea why?

Please fiddle with it here http://jsfiddle.net/As3JQ/12/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main code seems to be OK, I looked at your jsfiddle and all I did is add

```
html, body, #map_canvas { height: 100% }​
```

to the CSS area and it works fine for me